# Posting to Slack from AWS Lambda fails with getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, slack-api

I'm using the below code to post a file to Slack from a lambda function.
However when executed it fails with:
`http request failed getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND slack.com`

What is missing?

```
import { WebClient } from '@slack/web-api';

export async function sendCSVToSlack(
  token: string,
  channel: string,
  csv_string: string,
  file_name: string,
  comment: string,
): Promise<void> {
  const web = new WebClient(token);
  await web.files.uploadV2({
    channel_id: channel,
    file: Buffer.from(csv_string, "utf-8"),
    filename: file_name,
    initial_comment: comment,
  });
}
```